# Black and White overlay behind modal window

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

help needed once again.
Have a button that calls modal popup, that in turn calls div.overlay. css snippet of class `overlay`:

```
.overlay {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 100;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
```

pretty standard situation. What I need is, the overlay to acts as sort of filter for the background behind it, to paint the `body` black and white.
now I know there is `css` `grayscale()`, trouble is when I apply

```
body {
 filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

along with `.overlay` - my modal popup turns black and white as well..
Any ideas on how to achieve black and white body, that could not be interacted(cant click on anything behind modal) with like an overlay at the same time not to make modal window black and white too.

Comment: Please post a snippet.

Comment: Since the `filter` affects the element it's applied on, and its children, you need to move your body's background image to e.g. a child element, or a pseudo, and apply the filter to it.

Comment: can you post the html? i cant understend what you exectly need without..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

**1. [backdrop-filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter)**

This would be easiest way to do it, but browser support is very poor and pretty much only Safari 9+ supports it properly right now (it might work in Chrome behind a flag).

```css
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: grayscale(1);
  backdrop-filter: grayscale(1);
}

.inner {
  background-color: #f88;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bf/Rosa_Red_Chateau01.jpg/360px-Rosa_Red_Chateau01.jpg" width="200">

<div class="overlay">
  <div class="inner">
    Overlay
  </div>
</div>
```

**2. Overlay should not be a child of the `filter` element**

`filter` will be applied to the element itself and all of its children, therefore the overlay div should not be a child of the filter element if you do not want it to be affected.

In the following example, you would have to toggle the `grayed` class when you show/hide the overlay.

```css
.grayed {
  filter: grayscale(1);
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.inner {
  background-color: #f88;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="app grayed">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bf/Rosa_Red_Chateau01.jpg/360px-Rosa_Red_Chateau01.jpg" width="200">
  <!-- The rest of your app is in here -->
</div>

<div class="overlay">
  <div class="inner">
    Overlay
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Second option is great, thank you, although I forgot to mention it is a Vue js app, where Im not able to have 2 separate divs..

Comment: Why not? In that case, you would have 1 main app div, then inside *that* you can have one div for the overlay and another div containing everything else (which has the filter applied to it). You are free to append the overlay component `$el` to another place in the DOM if necessary.

Comment: As @DecadeMoon stated.. both answers are simply a logic of isolating **content** and **popup** so you can work with them separately.. and I guess this logic can be applied to any div, it's not supposed to be a direct child of the body only.

Answer (score 1):

If you're allowed to modify the html structure, you may wrap **all of your content** in a `div` and insert the **popup** outside of it, so you can apply the `filter` only to the Content when the popup is shown.

Example:

```
<body>

    <div id="content-wrapper">
        All of your content goes here
    </div>

    <div id="my-popup">
        This is my popup
    </div>

</body>
```

...now you simply add the `filter: grayscale(100%);` to the `content-wrapper` whenever the popup is shown.

To make it simpler.. you can control this by simply adding a class to your `<body>` whenever you want to show your popup, like so:

```
/* hide the popup initially */
#my-popup{
    display: none;
}

/* gray the content and show the popup 
 * when the class is added to the body
 */
body.is-popup-open #content-wrapper{
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}
body.is-popup-open #my-popup{
    display: block;
}
```